# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringSecurityLoginForm/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I tried to run a Spring Security Login Form application using spring mvc.

This is my URL:

```
http://localhost:8087/SpringSecurityLoginForm/
```

when I am adding login at the end of the URL:

```
http://localhost:8087/SpringSecurityLoginForm/login
```

When I am adding(manually) login at the end of the url, the login page appears and its displaying the username and password fields. But its not coming automatically. I have checked the controller mappping and tried some suggestion for the same topic but its not working. Please let me know the fault in the code to fix it.

My console:

```
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Riya/software_downloads/eclipse/jre/bin/server;C:/Riya/software_downloads/eclipse/jre/bin;C:/Riya/software_downloads/eclipse/jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;C:\app\Riya\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Riya\software_downloads\eclipse;;.
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:53 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringSecurityLoginForm' did not find a matching property.
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 445 ms
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Apr 21 12:12:55 EDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml]
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion performVersionChecks
INFO: You are running with Spring Security Core 3.2.1.RELEASE
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion performVersionChecks
WARNING: **** You are advised to use Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE or later with this version. You are running: 3.2.4.RELEASE
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
INFO: Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.2.1.RELEASE
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:55 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder
INFO: Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2e352f85: defining beans [loginController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,messageSource,dataSource,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager initDao
INFO: No authentication manager set. Reauthentication of users when changing passwords will not be performed.
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain <init>
INFO: Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@164a38ae, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@62cf32f0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@11195d3e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@18389a37, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@2c149d4d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7d6340d6, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7f35e1e9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2a82c93e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@706a1b3f, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4622fec1, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@238354e0]
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator checkLoginPageIsntProtected
INFO: Checking whether login URL '/login' is accessible with your configuration
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1050 ms
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Apr 21 12:12:56 EDT 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6398523f: defining beans [loginController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,messageSource,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2e352f85
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/login] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/login.*] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/login/] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/logout] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/logout.*] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/logout/] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome.*] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome/] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/loginfailed] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/loginfailed.*] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/loginfailed/] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 322 ms
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 21, 2014 12:12:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3104 ms
Apr 21, 2014 12:13:16 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringSecurityLoginForm/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

Spring-database.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
       <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
       <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcldatabase"/>
       <property name="username" value="SYSTEM" />
       <property name="password" value="oracleadmin"/>
       </bean>

       </beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">



            <http auto-config="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
            <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
                         authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
            <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
            </http>

            <authentication-manager>
              <authentication-provider>
                <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                   users-by-username-query="
                   select user_name,password, enabled from login_user where USER_NAME=?"

                   authorities-by-username-query="select u.user_name, ur.authority from login_user u,user_role ur 
                   where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.user_name=?" />


              </authentication-provider>
            </authentication-manager>     
    </beans:beans>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xsi:schemaLocation="
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

                       <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.common.controller"/>



                        <bean
                            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                            <property name="prefix">
                                <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
                            </property>
                            <property name="suffix">
                            <value>.jsp</value>
                            </property>
                        </bean>


                       <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
                       <property name="basenames">
                       <list>
                         <value>mymessages</value>
                       </list>
                       </property>
                       </bean>


                       </beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringSecurityLoginForm</display-name>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
     </param-value>
   </context-param>
   <!--  Spring Security -->
   <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
    <jsp-config>
     <taglib>
         <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
         <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/c.tld</taglib-location>
      </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login Page</title>
 <style>
 .errorblock {
 color: #ffEEEE;
 background-color: #ffEEEE;
 border: 3px solid #ff0000;
 padding: 8px;
 margin: 16px;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
  <h3>Login with Username and Password (Authentication with Database)</h3>

  <c:if test="${not empty error}">
   <div class="errorblock">
      Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br />Caused :
      ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
   </div>
   </c:if>

   <form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='GET'>
   <table> 
    <tr>
      <td>User:</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Password:</td>
     <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" />
     </td>
     </tr>
   </table>

   </form>
   </body>

</html>
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.spring.common.controller;

import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model)
    {
        User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String name=user.getUsername();

        model.addAttribute("username",name);
        model.addAttribute("message","Spring Security login + database example");
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model)
    {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/loginfailed", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginerror(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("error","true");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(ModelMap model)
    {
        return "login";
    }

}
```

mymessages.properties

```
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Invalid username or password
```

Comment: Seems for me `/SpringSecurityLoginForm` isn't contextPath of your app. But it is bound to the `/`. Try this `http://localhost:8087/login` for login page

Comment: I tried the url http://localhost:8087/login but its not working.If I have /login in the url then its working http://localhost:8087/SpringSecurityLoginForm/login

Comment: @Artem: I will add my Controller Class in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

You need to have this:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

instead of just `/welcome*`. Otherwise the Spring Security doesn't determine the root context `/` as a secured resource.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I will try this now and will get back to you.

Comment: I am getting 404 error. webpage cannot be found after making this change and If I try to add /login this time its not working and giving 404 after this change.

Comment: One more thing, its my general doubt may be its very basic since I am new to this technology am asking this. In many samples of spring hibernate, in the jsp they have method="POST" but in the controller request mapping method level, method=RequestMethod.GET. Even thought we have POST in JSP and we will have only GET in the request mapping. So it will map both? Please clear my doubt if you know answer for this question

Comment: Can anyone suggest me the fix for the above problem?

Comment: `POST/GET` is a different question.

Comment: yes. Its a different question but still even in this sample also in jsp they have mentioned POST but in the controller mapping all the methods are GET. So I just want to know, the error is related to this but even I have changed the method also m getting the same error. But why are they are giving like this?

Comment: I have fixed the problem. In the LoginController.java, Instead of value="/login" I gave value="/" inorder to map with the web.xml url pattern to pick the login page and now its showing the login page. I just want to know, Is this a good practise to do and is this a right fix?

Comment: Now the url is http://localhost:8087/SpringSecurityLoginForm/ instead of http://localhost:8087/SpringSecurityLoginForm/login and when I try to give the credentials in the http://localhost:8087/SpringSecurityLoginForm/ url its not showing the welcome user page. If someone clear my doubt at this point it will be very helpful for me to learn more about spring security and spring mvc

Comment: Actually, I don't use `Controller` for security urls. Just rely on Spring Security abilities

Comment: Do you have a sample for it. I am new to spring hibernate and am learning rigorously and developing an application

Comment: Try remove methods `login`, `loginerror` and `logout`

Comment: ok. I will try for it.